# Spring boot Joins with @Query annotation to fetch selected columns in Key and values pair from Mysql

Tags: mysql, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Here I'm using spring-boot with JPA, Mysql, and Restful Web services. I 
    need to fetch the data from 3 tables with joins concept. to execute the query 
    I'm using @Query annotation. while fetching the data it is giving only 
    values, 
    however, I'm expecting the key as well. Please find the below code for 
    reference. Thanks in advance.
    Here is the Controller class:

```
@Autowired
Active_DashBoard activedashBoard;

@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
value = "/logo")
   public List<Dashboard> logo(){

      List<Dashboard> dd = new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
      dd = activedashBoard.getList();

      return dd;
}

Here is the Service method

@Autowired
DashboradupdatesRepository dashboard;

public List<Dashboard> getList( ){
    List<Dashboard> al = new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
    al = dashboard.DataListStatusnull();
    return al;
}

Implemented Repository extending JpaRepository<Dashboard, Long>

@Query("SELECT du.consumed_bitrate,ac.timezonevalue_utc,ac.channel_id,cu.name 
as customer_name,du.location,du.new_date,du.datetime,cu.logo as 
customer_logo,du.imei,du.activestatus,du.new_date,ch.name as channel_name 
FROM Dashboard as du JOIN AndroidDevicevsChannels as ac ON ac.device_id = 
du.imei JOIN ChannelInfo as ch ON ch.channel_id = ac.channel_id JOIN 
CustomerInfo as cu ON cu.customer_id = ac.customer_id WHERE  (du.activestatus 
= 0 OR internetspeed='0') ORDER BY cu.name,ch.channel_id,du.imei ")

List<Dashboard> DataListStatusnull();



And I have 3 bean classes, each bean class represents a table. Used @Entity, 
and @Table, @column annotations where required.

Even checked with @OnetoMany etc, but not worked.
Please suggest on this.




1 bean class is :

package com.example.demo.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "dashboard_updates")
public class Dashboard {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String imei;
@Column(name = "internetspeed")
private String internetspeed;
private String datetime;
private int activestatus;

@Column(name = "streamstatus")
private String streamstatus;
private Date new_date;
private String channel_id;
private String ip_address;
private String location;

public String getDatetime() {
    return datetime;
}

public void setDatetime(String datetime) {
    this.datetime = datetime;
}

public int getActivestatus() {
    return activestatus;
}

public void setActivestatus(int activestatus) {
    this.activestatus = activestatus;
}

public String getStreamstatus() {
    return streamstatus;
}

public void setStreamstatus(String streamstatus) {
    this.streamstatus = streamstatus;
}

public Date getNew_date() {
    return new_date;
}

public void setNew_date(Date new_date) {
    this.new_date = new_date;
}

public String getChannel_id() {
    return channel_id;
}

public void setChannel_id(String channel_id) {
    this.channel_id = channel_id;
}

public String getIp_address() {
    return ip_address;
}

public void setIp_address(String ip_address) {
    this.ip_address = ip_address;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getGeo_lang() {
    return geo_lang;
}

public void setGeo_lang(String geo_lang) {
    this.geo_lang = geo_lang;
}

public String getGeo_lat() {
    return geo_lat;
}

public void setGeo_lat(String geo_lat) {
    this.geo_lat = geo_lat;
}

public String getLocation_history() {
    return location_history;
}

public void setLocation_history(String location_history) {
    this.location_history = location_history;
}

public String getIpaddress_history() {
    return ipaddress_history;
}

public void setIpaddress_history(String ipaddress_history) {
    this.ipaddress_history = ipaddress_history;
}

public String getConsumed_bitrate() {
    return consumed_bitrate;
}

public void setConsumed_bitrate(String consumed_bitrate) {
    this.consumed_bitrate = consumed_bitrate;
}

private String geo_lang;
private String geo_lat;
private String location_history;
private String ipaddress_history;
private String consumed_bitrate;

public String getInternetspeed() {
    return internetspeed;
}

public void setInternetspeed(String internetspeed) {
    this.internetspeed = internetspeed;
}

public String getImei() {
    return imei;
}

public void setImei(String imei) {
    this.imei = imei;
  }

 }

secound bean is : 

package com.example.demo.model;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_info")
public class CustomerInfo {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String customer_id;
private String name;
private String address1;
private String  address2;
private String country;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zip;
private String phone;
private String email;
private String logo;
//private Date created_date;
//private String created_date;
private int active_status;
private int delete_status;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCustomer_id() {
    return customer_id;
}
public void setCustomer_id(String customer_id) {
    this.customer_id = customer_id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress1() {
    return address1;
}
public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    this.address1 = address1;
}
public String getAddress2() {
    return address2;
}
public void setAddress2(String address2) {
    this.address2 = address2;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getZip() {
    return zip;
}
public void setZip(String zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getLogo() {
    return logo;
}
public void setLogo(String logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}

 /* public String getCreated_date() {
    return created_date;
}
public void setCreated_date(String created_date) {
    this.created_date = created_date;
}*/
public int getActive_status() {
    return active_status;
}
public void setActive_status(int active_status) {
    this.active_status = active_status;
}
public int getDelete_status() {
    return delete_status;
}
public void setDelete_status(int delete_status) {
    this.delete_status = delete_status;
}
public int getCreated_by() {
    return created_by;
}
public void setCreated_by(int created_by) {
    this.created_by = created_by;
}
private int created_by;

}

3 bean is :

package com.example.demo.model;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "channel_info")
public class ChannelInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String channel_id;
private String name;
private String link;
private String audio_bitrate;
private String video_bitrate;
private String video_type;
private int ads_status;
private String logo;
private int active_status;
private String player_code;
private Date created_datetime;
private int delete_status;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getChannel_id() {
    return channel_id;
}
public void setChannel_id(String channel_id) {
    this.channel_id = channel_id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getLink() {
    return link;
}
public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}
public String getAudio_bitrate() {
    return audio_bitrate;
}
public void setAudio_bitrate(String audio_bitrate) {
    this.audio_bitrate = audio_bitrate;
}
public String getVideo_bitrate() {
    return video_bitrate;
}
public void setVideo_bitrate(String video_bitrate) {
    this.video_bitrate = video_bitrate;
}
public String getVideo_type() {
    return video_type;
}
public void setVideo_type(String video_type) {
    this.video_type = video_type;
}
public int getAds_status() {
    return ads_status;
}
public void setAds_status(int ads_status) {
    this.ads_status = ads_status;
}
public String getLogo() {
    return logo;
}
public void setLogo(String logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}
public int getActive_status() {
    return active_status;
}
public void setActive_status(int active_status) {
    this.active_status = active_status;
}
public String getPlayer_code() {
    return player_code;
}
public void setPlayer_code(String player_code) {
    this.player_code = player_code;
}
public Date getCreated_datetime() {
    return created_datetime;
}
public void setCreated_datetime(Date created_datetime) {
    this.created_datetime = created_datetime;
}
public int getDelete_status() {
    return delete_status;
}
public void setDelete_status(int delete_status) {
    this.delete_status = delete_status;
}
```

}

```
the output is:


  [
    "",
    "5.5::2::+05:30",
    "CH_00090",
    "AKHUN KOLKATA",
    "",
    "2018-05-29T07:09:41.000+0000",
    "2018-05-29 18:05:30",
    "customer_logo_16032018131544.jpeg",
    "IB-AKHUN-TEST",
    1,
    "2018-05-29T07:09:41.000+0000",
    "AKHUNKOLKATA"
],
[
    "",
    "5.5::2::+05:30",
    "CH_00090",
    "AKHUN KOLKATA",
    "",
    "2018-03-19T05:21:57.000+0000",
    "2018-03-19 16:21:17",
    "customer_logo_16032018131544.jpeg",
    "TEST-KOLKATA",
    1,
    "2018-03-19T05:21:57.000+0000",
    "AKHUNKOLKATA"
]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can traverse the list and check your Entity to get the keys and values.

e.g.
your Dashboard entity will have fields and values populated for direct mapped/joins